# How to prevent app crash on SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade fail

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, versionupgrade

If there is an error during the onUpgrade method of my extended SQLiteOpenHelper class, the app crashes. I'd instead prefer to let the app continue opening the database and disable certain features that depend on the new schema.

I achieved it as follows, but feel this is a bit convoluted. Does anyone know a more supported or better way to let my app continue running on a failed database upgrade?

DBHelper class:

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public int _actual_version = 0;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "example_db_name", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        this._actual_version = oldVersion;

        try {
            //do some upgrade code

            this._actual_version = newVersion;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            //end the current transaction without committing
            db.endTransaction();
            //begin a new transaction to let the app continue
            //this also increments the db version
            db.beginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public int getActualVersion() { return this._actual_version; }
}
```

In my DB Adapter class:

```
class DBAdapter {
    private final DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase dbW;

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        dbW = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        if (dbHelper.getActualVersion() != 2) {
            dbW.beginTransaction();
            dbW.setVersion(dbHelper.getActualVersion());
            dbW.setTransactionSuccessful();
            dbW.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a stack trace of the app crash. I am simulating an error by using `CREATE TBLE` instead of `CREATE TABLE` in the query.

```
2021-09-13 09:00:00 7931-7931/com.example.android.myapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TBLE": syntax error in "CREATE TBLE setting (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, setting TEXT NOT NULL)"
2021-09-13 09:00:00 7931-7931/com.example.android.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.myapp, PID: 7931
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.myapp/com.example.android.myapp.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TBLE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TBLE setting (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, setting TEXT NOT NULL)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TBLE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TBLE setting (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, setting TEXT NOT NULL)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1841)
        at com.example.android.myapp.DBHelper.onUpgrade(DBHelper.java:159)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:416)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:340)
        at com.example.android.myapp.DBAdapter.<init>(DBAdapter.java:49)
        at com.example.android.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Is there any stack trace or error detail as to why the application crashes? Might be a null pointer exception as the database might not be initialised after a failed upgrade.

Comment: I think your application crashes because the database initialisation code runs on the main thread. Either catch the thrown exception and proceed with the code (very bad idea and you have to enclose the code with a new try catch) or initialise your database in a different thread (then you have the issue of starting the rest of the code AFTER your database is initialised)

Comment: I think Android invokes these methods automatically and so you may not be able to do the process in a separate thread. My advice is you may check the update SQL code yourself and only pass for onUpgrade method if there is no issue.

Comment: Your suspicion is right. Initialising the DB Adapter in a new thread also crashes the app, giving a fatal error.

Comment: Well there is only one way I guess... Check your SQL for errors before deployment. If the app crashes, user may have to clear cache or reinstall the app. Kudos!

Comment: I allow my users to define certain labels that may become standards / keywords defined by me in future updates, and I cannot foresee all issues, which is why I wanted the app to continue to work, so that any reported errors could be fixed while letting my users use the app. Guess I'll stick to my existing working solution, however convoluted it may be.

Comment: Why don't you handle the error and show a prompt to user saying "Error updating database. Please reinstall the app" or something?